# SQLite Python AND statement not working

Tags: python, database, sqlite, execute

I'm attempting to pull a list of rows from an SQLite database that are on a given day of the week and a certain hour of that day.
When I open my sqlite browser and type the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM points
WHERE strftime('%H', checkintime) == '12'
  AND strftime('%w', checkintime) == '1'
```

It works and I receive all of the rows I should be receiving.
However when I attempt to do this in python:

```
_points.execute("""SELECT * FROM points WHERE strftime('%H', checkintime) == ? AND strftime('%w', checkintime) == ?""", (time, day))
```

Where time is 12 and day is 1 I get zero results returned.
What's even more strange is when I change the `execute` statement to use hardcoded values, it works.

**I've attempted to typecast my vars to both strings and ints but its still a no go. :(**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you handle the string formatting outside of the execute call? For example,

```
sql_statement = """SELECT * FROM points WHERE strftime('%s', checkintime) == %s AND strftime('%s', checkintime) == %s""" % ('%H', time, '%w', day)

_points.execute(sql_statement)
```

This should avoid the string mapping that the execute statement is unable to accomplish.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you have to convert your number parameters to strings, otherwise they won't get quoted as you do in your statement in sqlite. The variable substitution with ? does not quote numbers.

You are actually comparing strings, so you must convert the parameters to strings.

Comment: I attempted to convert them to strings using str(day) etc, but no luck.    `_points.execute("""SELECT * FROM points WHERE strftime('%H', checkintime) == ? AND strftime('%w', checkintime) == ?""", (str(time), str(day)))`

Answer (score 1):

The time and day values do need to be strings.  Also, I wonder if your '%' needs escaping (with %%) -- It's possible that inside pysqlite the `?` placeholders get converted to %-style ones and then your %H and %w get misinterpreted. Does the following work?

```
_points.execute("""SELECT * FROM points WHERE strftime('%%H', checkintime) == ? AND strftime('%%w', checkintime) == ?""", (str(time), str(day)))
```

Comment: (1) "(or you need quotes in your query string)" is obscure and/or heresy -- please explain. (2) The placeholders don't get converted to %-style ones. A placeholder character inside a SQL string literal is not a placeholder ... in `select 'Huh??', foo from bar where zot = ?`, only the last `?` is a placeholder.

Comment: Nope, this doesnt work Neither the %%H or %H work :( And i dont really find it possible that the escpaing is happening that way, b/c all i need to do is replace the ? with '2' and it works.

Comment: @John: (1) good point! Edited. (2) What I mean is that if Python %-formatting gets done at some point when substituting placeholders, then the %s would need escaping. I have had this crop up in the past, although checking my old code it was with pymssql: I had to say `...like 'prefix%%' whenever there were placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:
_points.execute("""SELECT * FROM points WHERE strftime('%H', checkintime) == ? AND strftime('%w', checkintime) == ?"""**%**(time, day))

pay attention to %(time, day)

I'm not sure about the %H and %w , don't know what time and day format is

Comment: ValueError: unsupported format character 'H' (0x48) at index 38